# How to validate the Paypal success call back?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am new to payments using `Paypal`, How can i validate a `Paypal IPN`, I need any sample code or suggested links.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Below is the documents and sample codes for IPN:

Introducing IPN：
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

IPN code samples:
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

IPN Variables:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables

Comment: can I get sample code in c# (my project frame work ASP .NET MVC 5, )